# userDefaults save array of struct

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I have a struct and I am trying to save it into userDefaults

Here is my code..

```
struct savedCategory {
    var images = String()
    var imageLabel = String()
}


class SavedCategoryModel {
    static var categoryModel: [savedCategory] = []
}
```

Here is how i try to save it

```
class UserDefaultsConfig {

func saveData() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(SavedCategoryModel.categoryModel, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
}

func showList() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    SavedCategoryModel.categoryModel = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray")!
}

}
```

I have an error

> Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[savedCategory]'

How can i fix it?

Comment: `.categoryModel` isn't an array of `String`, it's an array of `savedCategory`

Comment: Make your savedCategory conform to Codable. Use this for saveData(): defaults.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(SavedCategoryModel.categoryModel), forKey:"SavedStringArray") 
And this for reading in showList():
if let data = defaults.value(forKey:"SavedStringArray") as? Data {
        SavedCategoryModel.categoryModel = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<savedCategory>.self, from: data)
    }